# JavaScript binary calculator not fully functional

Tags: javascript, dom, binary, numbers, calculator

I'm trying to create a base 2 calculator.  It is taking in numbers and when I console log (bin2) it's converting the numbers to base 10 but it isn't accepting the operators and doesn't seem to want to go back to base 2.  Any help would be much appreciated!

```
<body>
    <div id="calc">
        <div id="res"></div>
        <br>
        <div id="btns">
            <button id="btn0" value= "0">0</button>
            <button id="btn1" value= "1">1</button>
            <button id="btnClr">C</button>
            <button id="btnEql">=</button>
            <br>
            <button id="btnSum" value="+">+</button>
            <button id="btnSub" value="-">-</button>
            <button id="btnMul" value="*">*</button>
            <button id="btnDiv" value="/">/</button>
        </div>    
    </div>    
    <script>

        let screen = document.querySelector("#res");
        let equal = document.querySelector("#btnEql");
        equal.addEventListener("click", ekewl);
        let clear = document.querySelector("#btnClr");
        clear.addEventListener("click", klear);
        let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
        buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener("click", cal));
        var bin2 = 0;

        function cal(e){
            screen.innerHTML += this.value;
            let numsToConvert = screen.innerHTML;
            let numbers = /(\d+)/g;
            numsToConvert = numsToConvert.replace(numbers, function(match) {
                bin2 = (parseInt(match, 2));
                return bin2;
            })
            console.log(bin2)
            //screen.innerHTML = eval((bin2).toString(2));
        } 
        function ekewl(){
            screen.innerHTML = eval(screen.innerHTML+=this.value);
        }
        function klear(){
            screen.innerHTML = "";
        }

    </script>    
</body>
```

Comment: *it isn't accepting the operators*: I tried it and it seems to accept them. *doesn't seem to want to go back to base 2*:  `eval(screen.innerHTML+=this.value)` reads the `screen.innerHTML` as decimal. You need to convert it to binary. Then after summing, you need to convert that result to a binary string before writing it back.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  The number comes back as base-10 but if I try " + ,  -  , * , / " they don't seem to do the calculations for some reason.  And then I thought the parseInt() would convert back to base-2...no?

Comment: All of the operations work when I try it. They just all work in base 10.